# Given a column of numbers, return the row number in which the maximum value is present using LibreOffice SpreadSheet

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice

Let's say I have a column A:

```
    A
1 | 10
2 | 20
3 | 33
4 | 42
```

On line 5 I can calculate the maximum of the row: MAX(A1:A4), which returns 42. In row 6 I would like to get the row number for the maximum, i.e. row number 4. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A5** contains `=MAX(A1:A4)`
**A6** then should have formula `=MATCH(A5;A1:A4;0)`

A6 returns the n'th row of the search matrix where your value can be found.
Does this help to solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much, that works.
 
MATCH(SearchCriterion; LookupArray; Type)
"Returns the relative position of an item in an array that matches a specified value". NB: if in my example the values in the column started at row 5, the function would still return 4.  
Type=0 means that only exact matches are found.  will